# What is the difference between Set as an abstract data type and as an interface?

Tags: java, interface

I'm studying for my finals in java advanced course and I've learned that **Set** is both an abstract data type but also an interface. What is the difference with Set as ADT and as interface? How can it be both? Same thing with **Map**, which confuses me.

Comment: An interface is just a series of methods which define the behaviors laid out by the ADT.  At least, this is my take on your question.

Comment: All answers are assuming by ADT you don't mean 'Abstract Class'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Set" is a concept (an *abstract* data type: a container with no duplicates).

`Set` as defined in `java.util` is the definition of that concept as code.

Then there are implementations.